# How to deal with not being held to the same standards as co-workers?

Tags: bonus, expectations

I work as a secondary public school teacher. II am being held to higher standards than other staff. This is not just my own observation, but several other co-workers have pointed this out, as I got in trouble for things (e.g. once being late for 2 minutes to cafeteria duty), while others get away with much (e.g. skipping cafeteria duty for half the semester).

This issue is especially apparent in our evaluations, which cover most aspects of the job. The state created a standardized checklist for evaluating teachers. Those who get a good evaluation from the principal earn a $6000 bonus from the state. This is an extensive list, but includes things like, showing up on time for work, submitting lesson plans, having materials ready for substitute teachers, taking part in after-school activities, training co-workers, quality of teaching, etc.

I learned that, at the end of the year, several staff, who did not make their lesson plans, did not have substitute plans, were regularly late for work (making me have to watch their students in the morning), and blatantly messing around in the classroom, will be earning the $6000 bonus. Meanwhile, I consistently stayed on top of my duties throughout the whole year, but just earned a neutral 50% score on every item in my evaluation.

How to deal with not being held to the same standards as co-workers?

Comment: Talk to your union rep.

Comment: Consider finding a new post - whatever happens, the person responsible will not forget...So even if the union helps or you report it at state level or governors that person will do it or something next time round...

Comment: Much of this is "he said, she said". Do you have any documentation to support your claims? If not, you'll probably be hard pressed to find any relief from the situation. I'd urge you to talk to your union representative (assuming you are in a union), and she what they recommend.

Comment: In the future, I could keep records, such as when I am in the cafeteria to monitor students, but is it acceptable for me to keep a record when I see other co-workers not doing their jobs?

Comment: The seems like a loaded question. I should be evaluated the same as everyone else. I should not be called in and reprimanded and shouted at for little mistakes when others get away with completely neglecting the same responsibilities.

Comment: @Village You say you've been faltering in part because you're covering for others who aren't pulling their weight.  Have you been communicating this to upper management?  Not necessarily pointing fingers, but letting them know "I was late today by 2 minutes because I had to cover for X somewhere else." Maybe the ones making the decisions don't realize how much of other people's work you're actually doing.

Comment: Also, I wouldn't rcommend documenting when other people are slacking off in general (that's just going to get you hated, which won't help.)  However, you absolutely *should* document when you're taking over a task that someone else should have been doing.

Comment: More seriously, when I slip somewhere, even if just a little behind on something, I get reprimanded, and that ends up factoring into my evaluation. For example, grades must be entered before Monday, every week. I missed this once, because I was at a district training. I got pulled into the office and reprimanded. Others missed the training, hadn't even put in a single grade the entire quarter, and told me they never heard a complaint. Can I document this kind of discrepancy?

Answer (score 5):

Two important facts are missing from your question.

1. Is a particular single individual responsible for these evaluations? Is some sort of personal animosity happening?
2. Is some sort of prejudice in play (years of service, age, race, gender, disability, whatever)?

Can you find any allies or mentors among your colleagues? From them you might gain insight into your workplace's politics.  Can a union rep help you understand? The question you might ask is, "why do some people around here get favorable treatment?"

Once you understand the "why" you'll be able to decide about your future.  Play along with whatever game they're playing?  Find a new job under a different principal? Ask your union to intervene?

And, ask yourself this:  Is it in your power to change the situation by working harder or doing your job more perfectly than you already are? You make it clear your school administration doesn't much care about that.

I know a longtime public school employee who's under a lot of pressure from the principal and superintendent to quit before retirement age due to disability.  My friend says the union has been very helpful in resisting the pressure, but the pressure stays high.  It's unpleasant but just barely tolerable. My friend stays motivated because of strong dedication to the students.  Of course, your situation is worse because it's costing you bonus money.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes holding people to different standards can be very reasonable. Let's say you have two people - one person who's super good at their job and one person who's... not. It's not unreasonable that the person who's super good at their job be given more leeway.

The only problem with this is that often times how "good" you are is subjective. Like maybe getting to work an hour early doesn't actually make you any better at your job but it may give the perception that you're "good" at it.

idk your situation well enough to know if any of this applies but maybe your evaluator does? I guess my suggestion would be to talk to your evaluator and present them with the evidence. "*I did x, y and z whereas Bob didn't and yet Bob got a better evaluation than me. Why?*" At this point several things could happen:

1. They give you a satisfactory answer.
2. They justify it by saying something discriminatory, at which point, they may be opening themselves up for a lawsuit and may be giving you the push that you need to leave that employer and find another.

Comment: The opposite can happen too. People who are excellent at their jobs can be held to higher standards because their boss knows that there is more work that can be had (there is less value in whipping the useless donkey of an employee if all it will do is ee-ore).